# Youtube Direct API: Could not retrieve YouTube upload token: 400

Tags: java, youtube-api

I got this error when using Youtube Direct: ([link](http://code.google.com/p/youtube-direct/wiki/GettingStarted))
when i try to upload video to Youtube.

"Could not retrieve YouTube upload token: 400: Upload token returned  from YouTube API is null. Please make sure that all request parameters  are valid."

Its hosted on appspot. My app is authenticated and developer key is provided.
Did anyone had same problem?

EDIT:
It seems that script dosnt post sessionId

```
"POST /GetUploadToken?sessionId=undefined HTTP/1.1"
```

In debug log i get warning:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<errors><error><domain>yt:validation</domain>
<code>too_short</code>
<location type='xpath'>media:group/media:keywords/text()
</location></error></errors>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stupid error. The youtube requires "Video Title","Video Description" and "Tags". Those need to be at least two characters long.I was putting one.